# how to prove that the set of positive real numbers is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that R+ cardinality is c but i'm stuck at finding a bijection from R or even from (0,1].

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean irrational?

Comment: I edited the title from "rational" to "real", which I think was your intention.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: You want to either have $\mathfrak{c}$ there instead of your $\aleph$ or possibly $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a bijection from $\Bbb R^+$ to $\Bbb R$:

$$f(x)=\ln x$$

The inverse function is, of course,

$$f^{-1}(x)=e^x$$